# How can you map a nested enum when the parent object is mapped using ConstructingUsing()?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a 2 enums that differ in name and indexing:

```
public enum TemperatureMode
{
    Cool = 1,
    Hot = 2
}

public enum HeatMode
{
    Cool,
    Hot
}
```

These are part of 2 parent objects:

```
public class CoolingUnitDTO
{
    private string UnitName {get;set;}
    private decimal Temperature {get;set;}
    private TemperatureMode Mode {get;set;}

    public CoolingUnitDTO(string unitName, decimal temperature, Temperature mode)
    {
        UnitName = unitName;
        Temperature = temperature;
        Mode = mode;
    }
}

public class CoolingUnit
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Temperature {get;set;}
    public HeatMode Mode {get;set;}

    public CoolingUnit(string name, decimal temperature, HeatMode mode)
    {
        Name = name;
        Temperature = temperature;
        Mode = mode;
    }
}
```

I've created mappings like this:

```
public class MappingProfiles : Profile
{
    CreateMap<TemperatureMode, HeatMode>().ConvertUsingEnumMapping(opt => opt.MapByName()).ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<CoolingUnitDTO, CoolingUnit>().ConstructUsing(source => new CoolingUnit(source.UnitName, source.Temperature, source.Mode));
}
```

However, this complains about source.Mode and says it can't convert from TemperatureMode to HeatMode. How can I map a nested enum as part of the ConstructUsing()?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
CreateMap<CoolingUnitDTO, CoolingUnit>().ForCtorParam("name", o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.UnitName));
```

The rest of your config can be removed.
See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html.

Comment: If you can rename stuff, the `ForCtorParam` can be removed too.

Comment: So this will pick up the enum mapping automatically?

Comment: You can easily verify that.